# solving equation with polynomial and exponential terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I couldn't solve this equation for x :
$$x^{10} = e^x$$
solution always exists as exponential functions have faster growth than any polynomial function.

Comment: Not totally satisfying, but have you head of the [*Lambert-W Function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)? Also, try numerical.

Comment: Otherwise you can only employ a numerical method.

Comment: Just because we know a solution exists and the question is easy to write does not mean that the solution can necessarily be easily written and in particular does not mean it can be written with elementary functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, the analytical solutions of
$$x^n=e^x\qquad n >1$$ can only be given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). It could be worth you spend sometime reading the linked page since it is a very interesting one with more and more appications. If, here, on the serach bar, you just type *Lambert function*, you will notice $3088$ entries.

If $n$ is even, there are three roots
$$x_1=-n W_0\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)\qquad x_2=-n W_0\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\qquad x_3=-n W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

If $n$ is odd, there are two roots
$$x_1=-n W_0\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)\qquad x_2=-n W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

but, in the real domain, these roots will exist only if the argument is larger the $-\frac 1e$.

Just for your curiosity, I listed a few solutions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
 2 &-0.703467 \\
 4 &-0.815553&1.42961&8.61317 \\
 6 &-0.865650&1.22689&16.9989 \\
 8 &-0.894241&1.15537&26.0935 \\
 10 &-0.912765&1.11833&35.7715 \\
 12 &-0.925754&1.09560&45.9238 \\
 14 &-0.935371&1.08021&56.4726 \\
 16 &-0.942779&1.06910&67.3611 \\
 18 &-0.948661&1.06070&78.5464 \\
 20 &-0.953446&1.05412&89.9951
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_1 & x_2  \\
 3 & 1.85718&4.53640 \\
 5 & 1.29586&12.7132 \\
 7 & 1.18435&21.4649 \\
 9 & 1.13432&30.8673 \\
 11 & 1.10575&40.7938 \\
 13 & 1.08723&51.1526 \\
 15 & 1.07424&61.8773 \\
 17 & 1.06463&72.9189 \\
 19 & 1.05722&84.2396
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods will do the the job. Using Newton, Halley or Householder methods, there is not problem to look for the zero's of function
$$f_n(x)=x^n - e^x$$ However, for numerical efficiency, when you search for the positive solutions, I should recommend instead
$$g_n(x)=n\log(x) - x$$ which is much more linear.